# Symfony/MySQL: full text search syntax error for special chars

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, full-text-search

I've got a problem with full-text search query. It is being sent from the inside of Symfony (2.8) controller, if that's important. The code is:

```
// not processed text (apart from multiple spaces) from form:
$searchTerm = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', trim($data['query'])); 
// for full-text search:
$searchTermPhrase = str_replace(' ', '* ', $searchTerm) . '*';

$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
// as far as I remember, query taken from StackOverflow after some tests
$statement = $entityManager->getConnection()
                           ->prepare(
                             "SELECT COUNT(id) AS books_count
                              FROM book
                              WHERE
                              MATCH(title) AGAINST (:searchTermPhrase IN BOOLEAN MODE) > 5 
                              AND active = true
                              ");
$statement->execute(array('searchTermPhrase' => $searchTermPhrase));

$titlesCount = $statement->fetch();
$titlesCount = $titlesCount['books_count'];
```

Now, it works great. Most of the time. But if user puts some special chars inside, for example `(title)`, `"title"` etc., it fails:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
1064 syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting 
FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*'
```

I don't get it, I use parametrized query, it should automatically take care of such cases...? I don't want to end up stripping all non-alphanumeric characters, or testing, which exactly cause problems, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Got a bit worried today as I found a few error msgs in my logs. It is clearly someone how tries to sql inject. Using Symfony, Doctrine & Match Against. Did you ever find any solution/explaination?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is InnoDB issue, see this report https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72605. I've faced with same issue, changed engine to MyISAM it started to work

Answer (score 0):

Well, as mentioned, got the same problem. I looked at our code and it is clear that `BOOLEAN MODE` causes this problems.

First of all: `"title"` should work, while `"title` should throw the error above.

Take a look at all the boolean operators: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

With this mode you can provide great search experience by letting the user search for apples but not bananas: `+apple -banana`. But wrongly entered Parenthesis or Quotes break it logic.

Question is: is there a regex or function to detect if the search term is valid for boolean mode? Else it should default to `natural language mode`.